# HTML page on NAS server image not showing on mobile phone

Tags: html, image

I've made a simple html page with a picture frame on my NAS server for testing purposes. When I open the html page  on my computer it works just fine, but when I open the page on my phone using my qnap app it doesn't display the picture.

I've tried to link to a local picture instead of online picture but keep getting the same results.I've also tried to select another standard app on my phone but also without any good results